# modifying the list of lists

Tags: c++, stl, stl-algorithm

there is a structure like this:

```
  std::list<std::list<std::string>> data;
```

I need to go throu the top level list and append internal lists against some criteria. something like this:

```
  std::for_each(data.begin(), data.end(), 
                 [<some variable required for the logic>]
                 (const std::list<std::string>& int_list) {
         if(...) 
              int_list.push_back(...);
  });
```

you see this code is not valid, because for_each can't modify the sequence.
what would you recommend me to perform what I need (without modifying initial data structure)?

Comment: Can you not use [`transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform)?

Comment: transform requires additional copy of the list , is not it? to return this from predicate

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YQs6IC-vgmo       bjarne Stroustrup : Why you should avoid lists

Comment: You're the one who declared the parameter const. Did you try just removing that qualifier?

Comment: yes, it doesn't work even without const

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a C++11 [ranged based for loops](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) like:

```
std::list<std::list<std::string>> data;
for (auto & e : data)
{
    if (some_condition)
        e.push_back(some_data)
}
```